# Which Jakarta-light-web-server is to implement jax-ws and JMS specification?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, jax-ws, java-17

I have an application in which the following modules are:

1- `Jax-ws`

2- `JMS` and its implementation by `ActiveMQ Artemis` with the following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

3- the version of `JDK` is 1.8

4- Its application server is `Wildfly`

I want to change and upgrade my application to `JDK 17`(LTS), due to this migration the javax package is replaced with jakarta package.

My question is:

1- What except Wildfly is which supports `Jakarta-ws and jakarta-jms`? because Wildfly is so heavy for my solution.

2- Before for JMS configuration, the following dependency were:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

after migration to JDK-17, which dependency should to add to implement jakarta-jms by activemq

Comment: JDK 17 has nothing to do with Oracle hating the Java community and forcing the change to the `jarkarta` namespace.  JEE9 is what does that.  If you are using JAX-RS and ActiveMQ you're past worrying about heavy weight.  What is the end goal - just EE9?  JDK 17 can be used with all of the newer Wildfly releases.  To really thin down look at something like [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) though JMS is still going to be a beast.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [OpenLiberty](https://openliberty.io/), it is fully open source and supports [Java 17](https://openliberty.io/blog/2021/10/01/java17-210010.html) and [Jakarta EE 8 and 9](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/jakarta-ee.html). Moreover its fully composable, so you can pick and choose what [features](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/feature-overview.html) (APIs) you need in the server.

Comment: Thanks in advance, how do I get my solution as same as https://start.spring.io/?

Comment: I did not see any specification about JAX-WS of https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/jakarta-ee.html. I want both JAX-WS and JMS but there is not JAX-WS

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin Jax-ws is now called [Jakarta XML Web Services 3.0](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/xmlWS-3.0.html) and it is provided also. If you need older spec - 2.2 - it is also available https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/jaxws-2.2.html

Comment: [OpenLiberty starter is here](https://openliberty.io/blog/2021/08/20/open-liberty-starter.html)

Answer (score 0):

WildFly can be easily reduced to your usage since you can easily disable what you don't need. You may want to take a look at [Galleon](https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Galleon_Guide.html) as a way to provision your server tailored to your need.